# How can I create a tile perfect fitting seamless pattern tile of an irregular watercolor photo shape that overlaps on the tops part in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, digital-printing

I need to create a sort of brick by column perfect fit **SEAMLESS PATTERN TILE** of this watercolor image of mine for a print.The round part above goes on top in the tiling, vertically speaking and on the sides they fit right next to each other without empty spaces. Horizonatly the column (brick by column) should start a bit on the half of the column above and then again half above...please see reference below. **The pattern tile should be a square** lets say of 30x30 cms, therefore there should like 10 motifs apron horizontal (this can vary, is just to give an idea)

[image: This is the pattern motif][image: This is the general idea]

Answer (score 1):

Make a layer via copy with the selection of the tile

[image: Tile]

Put a horizontal  guide where the arc stars and draw a horizontal dash a pixel width using the **Pencil Tool** over this guide outside the image

[image: guide]

[image: dash]

Duplicate the layer and move it down until the dash touch the image bottom. Reduce the layer opacity to see exactly where to locate it:

[image: relocation]

Create the bottom guide, set the layer opacity to 100% and make a rectangular selection from guide to guide, the same width than the image

[image: selection]

**Menu Edit** > **Define Pattern**

Create a new document and fill it with the pattern:

[image: pattern]

---

**Add after the question edit:**

Duplicate the two tile layers to the right, 50% up:

[image: new tile]

Make a rectangular selection from guide to guide, the same width than the four layers and create a pattern.

[image: pattern]

Comment: Good but @Jo87 wants it to be a brick pattern look.

Comment: A seamless pattern tile... that looks like brick by column, indeed. Thanks!